# Организация релевантного поиска по базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Делаю для себя сайт и параллельно изучаю PHP, MySQL.
На одном из этапов появилась задача создать поиск по сайту. В моем случае пока только по одной таблице, таблице - страниц сайта (статические статьи). И я не до конца пока понимаю как это сделать лучше.

Исходные данные:
В базе данных таблица называется pages с простой структурой "id | name | description"
Запрос приходит в виде string переменной "searchquery" очищенной средствами php.

1. Первое что я придумал это входящий запрос searchquery вставлять в запрос к БД через LIKE % $searchquery %.
   Плюс: Работает
   Минус: Требуется хорошая фильтрация от атак и надо знать все страницы сайта чтобы их найти, иначе через поиск можно не найти нужную страницу.
2. Второе что пришло в голову это добавить к структуре таблицы колонку "Keywords"
   Но т.к. запрос от пользователя это некое предложение а ключевые слова в Keywords через запятую то LIKE тут не сработает.
3. Следующее что я сделал, на мой взгляд, имеет очень громоздкую структуру

- Извлекаю все данные из БД:

  $result = $db->query("SELECT id, name, description, keywords FROM pages");
  $result->execute();
- Записываю в массив:

```php
 $i=0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $searchList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $searchList[$i]['url'] = $row['name'];
            $searchList[$i]['description'] = $row['description'];
            $searchList[$i]['keywords'] = $row['keywords'];
            $i++;
        }
```

- Добавляю новое поле в массив:

```php
foreach ($searchList as &$sr) {
            $sr['index'] = "0";
        }
        $count = count($searchList) - 1;
        $i = 0;
```

- Сравниваю значения через функцию. Которая как я выяснил работает по алгоритму Оливера.

```php
while ($i <= $count) {
                $string = $searchList[$i]['keywords']; 
                $sim = similar_text($string, $searchquery, $perc);
                $searchList[$i]['index'] = $sim; 
                $i++;
            }
    
       function compare ($v1, $v2) {
            if ($v1["index"] == $v2["index"]) return 0;
            return ($v1["index"] > $v2["index"])? -1: 1;
          }
```

- Сортирую

  ~  usort($searchList, "compare");~

И на удивление все работает, страницы сортируются в зависимости от запроса и вверху списка более подходящие страницы, но есть и исключения. Конкретно нужная страница порой находится на третьем месте (по статистике).

Как можно сделать поиск лучше?

PS.
ключевые слова подбираются по частоте их использования в тексте, первые 15-25 слов из списка.

Comment: У MySQL есть, к примеру, полнотекстовый поиск. А можно и внешний поисковый движок подключить, тот же ластик например. *Минус: Требуется хорошая фильтрация от атак* Гм... у тебя ж в тегах вроде как PDO отметился...

Comment: Да, но фильтрация нужна была только в случае с LIKE. А когда я запрос пользователя в своем "движке" использую то думаю что уже не так важна. Но экранирование спец символов оставил.